# Load external ajax content into div with animation and "back" functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm developing an NFL fantasy web app with bootstrap & jQuery. I originally was using Framework7 because of the easy native app-like interface but abandoned it to develop a fully responsive page instead.

I have a div with a list of matchups and would like for the user to be able to click on one and see the matchup detail.  On Framework7, it would slide in an external ajax page, show a "back" button at the top which would easily slide that new div out and go back to the original one.

Is there an easy way to build this custom with jQuery?  I already have been messing with $.load() but I'm not sure of how to:

1) slide/animate that external page into the div I need, and

2) add a "back" or "close" button that will animate/hide the div and show the original div instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Please provide code that you're working with/have tried. The StackOverflow community is more receptive to specific questions about problems you're having rather than "How do I do this?" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, exactly as you said it...

```
$(divElement).load("newPage.html",function(){
      $(divElement).slideIn();
});
```

Then on the click action of a back button element in that newPage.html

```
$(backButton).on("click",function(){
     $(divElement).slideOut();
}
```